# 3 light tester shows dim yellow lights

Tags: wiring

I test the circuit with power on and tester shows circuit is good, with the switch turned off I get two yellow lights that are dim.
What would cause this?

Thanks

Charles

Comment: Are you inquiring as a Outlet Tester being used to test a switched wall outlet?  [LIKE THIS ONE](http://www.thecircuitdetective.com/outlet_tester_readings.htm)    If so these are for powered outlets once the switch is off they do not function properly, to check the outlet further would require something like a multimeter.

Comment: If the outlet is switched and the switch is lighted this could be the reason for the tester to be slightly illuminated.

Comment: Thanks Ed, the switch is lighted and is probably the reason, other than that the circuit operates as expected.